# npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY while npm install

Tags: npm, dockerfile

I get the below-mentioned error when trying to do NPM install in my Dockerfile. I do delete node_modules before running NPM install still I end up with this error.

```
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! path /nodejsAction/node_modules/setprototypeof
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 
'/nodejsAction/node_modules/setprototypeof'
```

Any idea how I can fix this? It seems to work properly on my local mac but on my Jenkins server the script fails.

Comment: you are using old version of node can you update?

Answer (score 48):

I think the following command might be more appropriate:

```
rm -r node_modules
```

This will remove the `node_modules` folder in your repository. The command `npm install` should work now.

If you are using Webpack, you can also remove the `dist` folder using `rm -r dist` and re-build your repository.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error/issue, and I removed the directory.

```
rm -r node_modules/MODULE
```

It simply worked!

Comment: This commands works perfectly for general cases. It doesn't do it job complete in case of NPM workspaces.

Comment: it should be rm -r node_modules, not rm -r node_modules/MODULE

Comment: Thank you, worked for me but my case was npm I bulma

Comment: For workspaces `rm -r node_modules */node_modules`

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, i did following:
1. Restart system
2. Close VS, VSCode or any editor that has JS files open. 
3. Apparently, you might have to do npm install in other directories too before doing it in target folder.

Comment: idk why but restarting my computer fixed the problem... haha.. wasted a few hours on this...

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the `ENOTEMPTY` followed an `ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT`. It also carried an instruction to rename the module (`uuid` to `uuid-<some string>`, `nanoid` to `nanoid-<some string>`)- renaming led to the same issue, with or without verifying the cache. The fix for this, without having to nuke the cache, was to delete both the source and destination modules

```
rm -r node_modules/<module>
rm -r node_modules/.<module>-<string suffix>
```

and then continue the install. Quite similar to an answer given here but deleting just the module wasn't enough for me

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was with Reactjs and when I was trying to install react-boostrap.

**Solution**

You should remove the node_modules directory in your project.
Run:

1. **rm -r node_modules**

or with superuser privileges

**sudo rm -r node_modules** . You need to enter your sudo password for this to work

2. Run **npm i** to reinstall your dependencies.

Sometimes you may end up with a type error if you're working with React, when you run **npm audit fix**. Type error like this:

```
*npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE*
```

If this is your case, you should replace your react-scripts version in package.json file to **^3.4.1** (*as this work for me*)

Remove the node_modules again and rerun **npm i**

It should be fine when you run **npm audit fix** and you can continue installing your dependency

Answer (score 1):

1. del node modules folder
2. del package-lock.json file
3. npm i
   OR
4. npm i --save --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 1):

Consider deleting package-lock.json. I ran into the same issue deleting it worked.

`rm package-lock.json`

Answer (score 0):

Error message say that `/nodejsAction/node_modules/setprototypeof` is not empty

You have to remove this directory or rename this directory in my case I removed this particular directory

This error show that to Install or update NPM Package you have to remove the particular directory

Answer (score 0):

rm -r node_modules && rm -r dist

Answer (score 0):

If there's a rename attempt and it fails, the system throws the error. The rename fails because there's already a backup package with a `.module<uuid>` present.  You should delete all backup packages. You may need to backup `.package-lock.json`

```
mv node_modules/.package-lock.json node_modules/package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules/.*
mv node_modules/package-lock.json node_modules/.package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 0):

on installing angular (updating to higher versions) just delete node_modules and reinstall

then try again with cli

Answer (score 0):

Check the terminal for the error it will ask you to rename a particular file in the node_modules
You can rename or delete the file and then install your desired package
example below
(base) Joesephs-Air:qr-code-scanner joseph$ npm install  @material-ui/core
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/joseph/Documents/qr-code-scanner/node_modules/**jss**
npm ERR! dest /Users/joseph/Documents/qr-code-scanner/node_modules/**.jss-HuFTkkaf**

in my case the files are in bold, do this instead of deleting and reinstalling the entire node_modules because it may not work