# How to install correctly @vue/cli

Tags: npm, vue-cli

Command:
`npm install -g @vue/cli`

[image]

What is the problem?
The running environment is iPad.
App is named Code.
node v12.19.0
npm v8.4.1

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /private/var/moble/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/0A5F620F-9DE9-49DC-9139-DDF9AA52EA48/lib/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli
npm ERR! dest /private/var/moble/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/0A5F620F-9DE9-49DC-9139-DDF9AA52EA48/lib/lib/node_modules/@vue/.cli-y8nVRrYF
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, renam '/private/var/moble/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/0A5F620F-9DE9-49DC-9139-DDF9AA52EA48/lib/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli'->'/private/var/moble/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/0A5F620F-9DE9-49DC-9139-DDF9AA52EA48/lib/lib/node_modules/@vue/.cli-y8nVRrYF'
```

Comment: I think the command is `npm i @vue/cli`

Comment: It says directory not empty try removing files of that directory. `rm -r node_modules` 
see this solutions it's not the same package but the error pattern looks same https://stackoverflow.com/q/43778883/11168176

Comment: The newly created folder runs npm，

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: No,Or continue to report errors.